# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine t ype for: com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, dropwizard

I'm new to hibernate and web services and creating a project for tailor system in dropwizard.
When i try to run the project through cmd as in [DropWizard Sites](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/) gets:

```
INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:13,784] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version: HCANN0
00001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:13,828] org.hibernate.Version: HHH000412: Hibernate Core
{4.1.9.Final}
INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:13,847] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment: HHH000206: hibern
ate.properties not found
INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:13,850] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment: HHH000021: Byteco
de provider name : javassist
INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:14,076] com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFa
ctory: Entity classes: [com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CoatModel, com.yammer
.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.LongS
hirtModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.OrderModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.
tailor.model.ShirtModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.TailorModel, com.yam
mer.dropwizard.tailor.model.TrouserModel]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine t
ype for: com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel, at table: Order, for
columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(customer)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:4
69)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
 a:1742)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory.buildSessionFac
 tory(SessionFactoryFactory.java:77)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory.build(SessionFa
 ctoryFactory.java:35)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.j
ava:38)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.j
ava:13)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap.runWithBundles(Bootstrap.java:
64)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.j
ava:37)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.jav
a:58)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:53)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.Service.run(Service.java:61)
    at com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.service.TailorService.main(TailorService
.java:25)
```

Classes:

CustomerModel class:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
    name = "com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel.findAll",
    query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerModel c"
),
@NamedQuery(
    name = "com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel.findById",
    query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerModel c WHERE c.ID = :ID"
)
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class CustomerModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "c_id")
int ID;
@Column(name = "c_code")
String customerCode;
@Column(name = "c_fname")
String firstName;
@Column(name = "c_mname")
String middleName;
@Column(name = "c_lname")
String lastName;
@Column(name = "c_nic")
String NIC_Number;
@Column(name = "c_email")
String email;
@Column(name = "c_pnumber")
String number;


public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getCustomerCode() {
    return customerCode;
}

public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
    this.customerCode = customerCode;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getNIC_Number() {
    return NIC_Number;
}

public void setNIC_Number(String NIC_Number) {
    this.NIC_Number = NIC_Number;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}}
```

which other class should i list??

please help me.

More class:

Database Configuration class:

```
public class databaseConfiguration extends Configuration {

@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
DatabaseConfiguration dbconfigurations = new DatabaseConfiguration();

public DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration() {
    return dbconfigurations;
}
}
```

.YML file

```
dbconfigurations:
# the name of your JDBC driver
driverClass: org.sqlite.JDBC

 # the username
user:

# the password
password:

url: jdbc:sqlite:TailorDB.db
```

Service Class:

```
public class TailorService extends Service<databaseConfiguration> {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TailorService().run(args);
}
private final HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration>(CustomerModel.class,OrderModel.class,CoatModel.class,LongShirtModel.class,ShirtModel.class,TailorModel.class,TrouserModel.class) {
    @Override
    public DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration(databaseConfiguration configuration) {
           return configuration.getDatabaseConfiguration();
    }
};

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<databaseConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bootstrap.setName("tailor");
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);

}

@Override
public void run(databaseConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final CustomerDAO cdao = new CustomerDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    final OrderDAO odao = new OrderDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    environment.addResource(new TailorResource(cdao,odao));

}

}
```

Comment: share your hbm.xml file

Comment: i just have pom.xml file in project.
and i'm using Annotations in entity classes.do i still need hbm.xml?

Comment: Ohh. Ya just realized. No not at all. I am an old school hibernate user.

Comment: ok..any solution in this case??

Answer (score 1):

After the first glance it seems that your sessionFactory don't know about the CustomerModel entity. Make sure it is added into the sessionFactory as a mapping file.

Comment: Hibernate in Dropwizerd they wrote 

"private final HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration>(Person.class) "

So i Added 

HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration>(CustomerModel.class,OrderModel.class,CoatModel.class,LongShirtModel.class,ShirtModel.class,TailorModel.class,TrouserModel.class)

Into my project.

Comment: is it write?
And I'm using Annotations in entity classes.so do i still need mapping file??

Comment: And also

                                                                    INFO  [2014-01-18 08:41:14,076] com.yammer.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFa
ctory: Entity classes: [com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.CoatModel, com.yammer
.dropwizard.tailor.model.CustomerModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.LongS
hirtModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.OrderModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.
tailor.model.ShirtModel, com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.TailorModel, com.yam
mer.dropwizard.tailor.model.TrouserModel]

Comment: You still need a sessionFactory config which should contain a list of all entities! Could you share this? Make sure that the sessionFactory defines your entities.

Comment: How do i do that? and shared .yml file code,configuration class code and of service class in post

Answer (score 1):

From the other proposed answer: "Make sure it is added into the sessionFactory as a mapping file."
This is probably exactly what Dropwizard is trying to avoid. However, they did a really bad job at their tutorial page here http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/hibernate/

Basically, follow that page, this error is guaranteed what you will get. Because it did not cover a very important part. Someone was too careless or too lazy to copy paste the "Person" class they use in the tutorial. Here is it from https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/core/Person.java

```
package com.example.helloworld.core;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll",
        query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"
    ),
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findById",
        query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :id"
    )
})
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "fullName", nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "jobTitle", nullable = false)
    private String jobTitle;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }
}
```

Now you can see that at the top, there is the annotation specify that this class is an entity and the table name. I spent 2 hours try to make sense of this problem. What were they thinking leaving this out of the tutorial!